# Location of the cells in a tableLayoutPanel when they are created dinamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I create the rows and columns of a tableLayoutPannel dinamically. I create 8 rows and 2 columns correctly (verified with a breakpoint after creating the rows and columns). However, the position of the screen is not what I want (see screenshot). I want the tableLayoutPannel embeddeded inside of the bottom splitContainer (splitContainer.Panel2). I would also like that it completely fills it vertically and horizontally. How can I do that?

This is the hierarchy for the UI elements:

[image: UI elements]

The code for generating the rows and columns dinamically:

```
tlpCharts.ColumnCount = 2;
tlpCharts.RowCount = _numChannels;

for (int chIdx = 0; chIdx < _numChannels; chIdx++)
{
    tlpCharts.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
    tlpCharts.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 10F));
    tlpCharts.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 90F));

    var cbEnableChannel = new CheckBox();
    // customize chEnableChannel

    var tmpChart = new Chart();
    //customize tmpChart
    tmpChart.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left);

    // Add chart and checkbox
    tlpCharts.Controls.Add(tmpChart, 0, chIdx})
        tlpCharts.Controls.Add(cbEnableChannel, 1, chIdx);
   }
```

And the screenshot. Notice that chart number 0 and 1 are below splitContainer.Pannel1 and the columns don't fill all the space horizontally but they do it vertically.

[image]

**EDIT**
I moved the columnStyles out of the loop and also added background color to see what is happening. These are the errors:

- charts should be in column 1 instead of column 0.
- buttons should be in column 0 instead of column 1.
- Width of columns is not correct. I tried 30%, 70% and it does not update.
- tableLayoutPanel top is in the form instead of the splitContainer.Panel2. Notice that the first chart is behind the first pannel.

  [image]

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

  ```
      tlpCharts.ColumnCount = 2;
      tlpCharts.RowCount = _numChannels;

      tlpCharts.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      tlpCharts.BackColor = Color.Blue;

      tlpCharts.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
      tlpCharts.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));

      for (int chIdx = 0; chIdx < _numChannels; chIdx++)
      {
          tlpCharts.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));

          var cbEnableChannel = new CheckBox();
          // customize chEnableChannel

          var tmpChart = new Chart();
          //customize tmpChart
          tmpChart.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left);

          // Add chart and checkbox
           tlpCharts.Controls.Add(cbEnableChannel, 0, chIdx);
           tlpCharts.Controls.Add(tmpChart, 1, chIdx);
         }
  }
  ```

And the elements:

```
 // 
            // splitContainer1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.splitContainer1.FixedPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel1;
            this.splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
            this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
            this.splitContainer1.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal;
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.tlpTop);
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel2
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.tlpCharts);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
            this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 561);
            this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 72;
            this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tlpTop
            // 
            this.tlpTop.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.tlpTop.ColumnCount = 4;
            this.tlpTop.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
            this.tlpTop.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
            this.tlpTop.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
            this.tlpTop.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            this.tlpTop.Controls.Add(this.grpOptions, 2, 0);
            this.tlpTop.Controls.Add(this.btnPlay, 0, 0);
            this.tlpTop.Controls.Add(this.grpDisplay, 1, 0);
            this.tlpTop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.tlpTop.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10);
            this.tlpTop.Name = "tlpTop";
            this.tlpTop.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 2, 0, 2);
            this.tlpTop.RowCount = 1;
            this.tlpTop.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            this.tlpTop.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(781, 71);
            this.tlpTop.TabIndex = 0;

 // 
            // tlpCharts
            // 
            this.tlpCharts.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.tlpCharts.ColumnCount = 1;
            this.tlpCharts.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
            this.tlpCharts.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 66.66666F));
            this.tlpCharts.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 5);
            this.tlpCharts.Name = "tlpCharts";
            this.tlpCharts.RowCount = 1;
            this.tlpCharts.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 21.16183F));
            this.tlpCharts.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(780, 478);
            this.tlpCharts.TabIndex = 0;
```

Comment: You didn't attach the screenshots

Comment: @Bayeni I think the last picture IS the screenshot

Comment: I really can't see it, have you tried using Dock instead of Anchor ?

Comment: I tried Dock = fill in the tableLayoutPannel and it has exactly the same behaviour. Same for Dock=fill in the charts.

Comment: Are you doing all this only once (in constructor or form load) or multiple times?

Comment: There's an obvious bug in the code, the tlpCharts.ColumnStyles.Add() calls need to be moved out of the loop.  You want 2 columns, not 2 * _numChannels columns.  And use the Dock property to get both the TLP and the charts to fill up the available space.

Comment: I am doing it on form load. I also replaced the tlpCharts.ColumnStyles but I guess I have other bugs I cannot find. I added it on the questions, please see EDIT part.

Comment: Top banner contains another tablelayout and a few buttons and labels. I added the code now.

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95077/discussion-between-nabrugir-and-larstech).